# How to play a video like you tube player in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

I am newbie for ios development, I am working on a project ,where i need to show some sample videos.

i Would like to show the video in streaming format(youtube player) .

```
-(void) playVideoOfURL:(NSString*)videoPath
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",TipsService,videoPath];

    moviePlayer = [[ MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
    if (moviePlayer)
    {

        moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill; 
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
        //Register for the playback finished notification.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];

        //setup device rotation notification observer
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];   
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil]; 

        UIViewController *player = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        player.view = moviePlayer.view;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:player animated:YES];
        [moviePlayer play];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:TRUE];

    }
}
```

I tried this one, but no use. Please help me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions, please try to be as descriptive as possible. When you say you tried that, but it was "no use", please explain WHY it was no use and what you have tried to make it work, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 [moviePlayer play];
 [moviePlayer setFullscreen:TRUE];
 UIViewController *player = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 player.view = moviePlayer.view;

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:player animated:YES];
```